# Unexpected '{' in the coffee script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I write some lines to init the jquery-ui date picker in coffee script

```
#this code is working fine
$(".picktime").datepicker
  numberOfMonths: 1

#this give me an Error: Parse error on line 3: Unexpected '{'
$(".picktime").datepicker
  numberOfMonths: 1
  showButtonPanel: true
```

Thank you.

Comment: I've never used coffee script before, but you sure you don't need a comma between object parameters?

Comment: I can't see any brace in your code...

Comment: @sp00m Coffeescript involves a translation to JavaScript, so the syntax error is probably in the form of a JavaScript syntax error introduced by an (unreported, apparently) syntax error in the source.

Comment: It seems okay: http://tinyurl.com/cemeeqk

Comment: Check your whitespace; make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: @sp00m, [take a look](http://coffeescript.org/).  I think that may be normal.

Comment: @Neil Sure, I don't need a comma between object parameters.More example: [link](http://bloggemdano.blogspot.com/2011/07/jquery-ui-examples-in-coffeescript.html)

Comment: Ah, the joys of significant whitespace: syntax errors that are invisible to the naked eye. I'll continue to enjoy my curly braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting as answer:

Check your whitespace; make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces.